# Regex to match anything (including the empty string) except a specific given string

Tags: sql, mysql, regex, pcre

I'd like to test whether a string contains `"Kansas"` followed by anything other than `" State"`.

Examples:

```
"I am from Kansas"          true
"Kansas State is great"     false
"Kansas is a state"         true
"Kansas Kansas State"       true
"Kansas State vs Kansas"    true
"I'm from Kansas State"     false
"KansasState"               true
```

For [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), I believe the answer is this:

```
'Kansas(?! State)'
```

But Mysql's REGEXP doesn't seem to like that.

ADDENDUM: Thanks to [David M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182811/david-m) for generalizing this question:
[How to convert a PCRE to a POSIX RE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837706/how-to-convert-a-pcre-to-a-posix-re)

Comment: Why `"Kansas Kansas State"` is true?

Comment: Because it contains "Kansas" followed by something other than " State", namely "Kansas State".  The rationale is that I want all strings that mention "Kansas", whether or not they also mention "Kansas State".  For example, "Kansas and Kansas State played each other in the tournament."  That mentions Kansas (not just Kansas State) so I want to match on it.

Comment: I added a couple more examples to clarify this.

Comment: i updated my answer. see if my new regex works in mysql.

Comment: poster pointed out that converting the simple PCRE to a full POSIX re can be tedious, which raises the interesting question about how to do it automatically.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837706/how-to-convert-a-pcre-to-a-posix-re

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More efficient than that large regex (depending, of course, on your data and the quality of the engine) is

```
WHERE col LIKE '%Kansas%' AND
  (col NOT LIKE '%Kansas State%' OR
  REPLACE(col, 'Kansas State', '') LIKE '%Kansas%')
```

If Kansas usually appears in the form 'Kansas State', though, you may find this better:

```
WHERE col LIKE '%Kansas%' AND
  REPLACE(col, 'Kansas State', '') LIKE '%Kansas%'
```

This has the added advantage of being easier to maintain.  It works less well if Kansas is common and text fields are large.  Of course you can test these on your own data and tell us how they compare.

Comment: Wow, yes, this seems much better.  (Performance was not an issue in my case but this is just much easier to type, not to mention to generalize.)  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

MySQL doesn't have lookaheads. A workaround is to make two tests:

```
WHERE yourcolumn LIKE '%Kansas%'
  AND yourcolumn NOT LIKE '%Kansas State%'
```

I used `LIKE` here instead of `RLIKE` because once you split it up like this, regular expressions are no longer required. However if you still need regular expressions for other reasons you can still use this same technique.

Note that this does not match 'Kansas Kansas State' as you requested.

Update: If matching 'Kansas Kansas State' is that important then you can use this ugly regular expression that is supported by MySQL:

```
'Kansas($|[^ ]| ($|[^S])| S($|[^t])| St($|[^a])| Sta($|[^t])| Stat($|[^e]))'
```

Oops: I just noticed Kip already updated his comment with a solution very similar to this.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  The 'Kansas Kansas State' issue is the crux though.  See the comment I added to the question about this.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, assuming look-ahead assertions are allowed in MySQL regexes.

```
/Kansas(?! State)/
```

---

**Edit**: OK, this is super ugly, but it works for me in Perl and doesn't use a look-ahead assertion:

```
/Kansas(([^ ]|$)| (([^S]|$)|S(([^t]|$)|t(([^a]|$)|a(([^t]|$)|t([^e]|$))))))/
```

Comment: Thanks Kip, I was just editing the question to this effect when you added this answer!

Comment: great answer, except that MySQL doesn't implement look-ahead assertions.

Comment: Re: Edit: Wow, I'm impressed! :)  Unfortunately MySQL responds to that with "Illegal variable name."

Comment: @Kip, you basically constructed a (regular) regex that matches the complement language of " State". Since the complement of a regular language ist regular (see [Regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties)), this is always possible, albeit usually ugly.

Comment: @dreeves: I just tried this on a MySQL database and it worked:  `SELECT 'This is Kansas State' REGEXP 'Kansas(([^ ]|$)| (([^S]|$)|S(([^t]|$)|t(([^a]|$)|a(([^t]|$)|t([^e]|$))))))' as REGEXRESULT`

Comment: It is important to note that Perl and MySQL have completely different regular expression implementations.  For straightforward examples, like the one that Kip and I implemented separately, they should perform very much the same.  However, don't count on Perl and MySQL to give the same answers or to similar performance.

Comment: @Kip: Ah, you're right.  I was doing it with the -e switch on the command line.  It does work as you describe at the MySQL prompt itself.  And I've now confirmed that your regex matches perl's 'Kansas(?! State)' for the data set I'm working with.  Nice!  It's a little painful to generalize your solution though! :)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Super helpful.  Seems like MySQL should get with the program and just implement pcre, eh?

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but here you go:

You might not need to expand the regex all the way to the end, depending on whether your input might include something like 'I need to get this man to surgery in Kansas Stat!'

```
mysql> select x,x RLIKE 'Kansas($|[^ ]| ($|[^S])| S($|[^t])| St($|[^a])| Sta($|[^t])| Stat($|[^e]))' AS result from examples;
+------------------------+--------+
| x                      | result |
+------------------------+--------+
| I am from Kansas       |      1 |
| Kansas State is great  |      0 |
| Kansas is a state      |      1 |
| Kansas Kansas State    |      1 |
| Kansas State vs Kansas |      1 |
| I'm from Kansas State  |      0 |
| KansasState            |      1 |
+------------------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks!  And I love how you demonstrated that it works on all the examples!