# regular expression which start with "/start/" but does not end with "end1" or "end2"

Tags: regex, apache, location, httpd.conf

I was trying to formulate a regular expression to be used with "Location" directive of Apache web server configuration inside httpd.conf file.

```
<Location ~ "/start/.*(?!end1|end2)$"> 
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from foo.com
</Location>
```

However, I got the following error in Apache log file:

```
Syntax error on line 1179 of c:/apache/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Regex could not be compiled
```

I know the error is probably in the "negative lookahead" section: (?!end1|end2), but could not figure out exactly.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of apache are you using?  The regex syntax changed dramatically between 1.x and 2.x

Comment: This is the Apache which comes from Oracle Application Server 10g and should be based on Apache 1.3.

Comment: Even with lookahead, the expression: `/start/.*(?!end1|end2)$` will not work. To ensure the location begins with `/start/` and does NOT end in either `end1` or `end2`, here is one expression that works: `^/start/(?!.*end[12]$)`

Answer (score 1):

Apache 1.x uses POSIX Extended Regular Expressions and with these expressions

**lookaround** is not supported.

So your problem lies here : `(?!end1|end2)`

Comment: He's looking for strings which "**do not** end with “end1” or “end2”"

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will do some research of POSIX Extended Regular Expressions. But is there a way to express "not ending with end1 or end2" in POSIX Extended Regular Expressions if you know of the top of your head?

Comment: @XiaopingWen This is not trivial to do with POSIX ERE, I don't even know it it's possible.. You can take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837706/how-to-convert-a-pcre-to-a-posix-re but I guess you will be needing a lazy quantifier .*? which also does not exist in POSIX ERE.

Comment: You are right that POSIX ERE just does not have the expressive power. Fortunately, my main goal is to protect a limited set of endpoints while allow URLs with two kinds of endings. I guess I will have to protect the endpoints one by one, each with a <Location> directive.

Answer (score 0):

Forward slashes generally need to be escaped:

```
 "\/start\/.*(?!end1|end2)$"
```

Comment: ^\/start\/.*(?!end1|end2)$ if it needs to start with /start/

Comment: It complained the same. "/" is probably not the problem as I have another simpler regex which uses "/" but works fine.